# Automatically connect nodes without overlapping other nodes or connections

Tags: tikz-pgf, automation

In making a tree diagram with TikZ. Say that I've got the following nodes

```
\node(a) {\(A\)};
\node(b1) at ($(a)+(4,1)$){\(B_1\)};
\node(b2) at ($(b1)+(0,-1)$){\(B_2\)};
\node(c) at ($(b1)+(1,-0.9)$){\(C\)};
\node(d) at ($(c)+(2,0)$){\(D\)};
\node(e) at ($(d)+(1,0.5)$){\(E\)};
```

and that I want to draw the following connections

- `(a)` to `(b1)`
- `(a)` to `(b2)`
- `(b1)` to `(d)`
- `(b2)` to `(e)`

but I want no or as few connections as possible to overlap another node or another connection (*without* changing the placement of the nodes).

If I draw straight lines between the nodes

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(a) {\(A\)};
\node(b1) at ($(a)+(4,1)$){\(B_1\)};
\node(b2) at ($(b1)+(0,-1)$){\(B_2\)};
\node(c) at ($(b1)+(1,-0.9)$){\(C\)};
\node(d) at ($(c)+(2,0)$){\(D\)};
\node(e) at ($(d)+(1,0.5)$){\(E\)};
\draw[->] (a) to (b1);
\draw[->] (a) to (b2);
\draw[->] (b1) to (d);
\draw[->,red] (b2) to (e);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I end up with an overlap of *C* and an overlap of the line *B₁* and *D* (the red line):

[image: Straight lines between nodes overlaps another node and another line]

Also, if I make the lines somewhat curved

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(a) {\(A\)};
\node(b1) at ($(a)+(4,1)$){\(B_1\)};
\node(b2) at ($(b1)+(0,-1)$){\(B_2\)};
\node(c) at ($(b1)+(1,-0.9)$){\(C\)};
\node(d) at ($(c)+(2,0)$){\(D\)};
\node(e) at ($(d)+(1,0.5)$){\(E\)};
\draw[->] (a) to[out=20,in=180] (b1);
\draw[->] (a) to[out=0,in=180] (b2);
\draw[->] (b1) to[out=0,in=160] (d);
\draw[->,red] (b2) to[out=0,in=180] (e);
\draw[->,red,dashed] (b2) to[out=-40,in=240] (e);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I get the same kind of overlap:

[image: Curved lines between nodes overlaps another node and another line]

What I'm after is a result like the dashed red line that don't overlap anything *but without* having to manually set what angles the lines should enter and exit nodes from.

In short, is there a way to avoid overlaps of nodes and other lines except for manually changing angles for lines, i.e. can I tell TikZ to avoid drawing over other nodes and lines and draw around them instead?

Comment: this is beyond my tex ability to make a fool proof code but maybe using the `intersection` library, you can check if there is any cross-over and resort to `bend` option if there is any, then simply comparing the vertical coordinate of end-points decide over or under pass.

Comment: Hmm, while your problem is yet quite simple, this is a highly non-trivial task. My guess would be that it is comparable to the "traveling salesman" problem, so the computation power required will probably rise with more than n², so doing this inside LaTex is probably not a good idea.

Comment: I'm guessing this would be an awesome feature that is going to be super-duper hard to automate. A bounty may initiate the willingness to overcome the super-duper-ness. Regardless, without sufficient general use for it (since the manual intervention might be minimal in many cases, or automation might yield sub-optimal results like pushing the dashed arrow between B_1 & C), super-duper-ness may reign supreme.

Comment: Aha, I found it: [graphs may be planar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph), but a graph with 5 vertices may well be not. So there is no general solution. But perhaps someone has the _time and ability_ to check if planarity is possible (see the link) and then implement a solution?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have a very strong suspicion that the general problem is not really tractable by TeX/TikZ.  This is based on the fact that there are programs like graphviz which have really complicated routines for solving this sort of problem.  Moreover, I think that it's going to be impossible in general in that there will be configurations where there is no solution with no crossings.

So what I have to offer is the following code.  This defines a `to` path which goes from its start to its end through a particular point.  The intention being that you use it to avoid a node by saying that you want your path to go through a particular corner of the node you want to avoid; thus we use the node as the region to avoid.

To make the problem tractable, I've used a different family of curves than is used by the `to[out=angle, in=angle]` curves.

Here's the proof-of-concept code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27899/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  through point/.style={
    to path={%
      \pgfextra{%
        \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone(\tikztostart)\relax
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pt@sx}{\pgf@x * 0.03514598035}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pt@sy}{\pgf@y * 0.03514598035}%
        \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1\relax
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pt@ax}{\pgf@x * 0.03514598035 - \pt@sx}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pt@ay}{\pgf@y * 0.03514598035 - \pt@sy}%
        \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone(\tikztotarget)\relax
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pt@ex}{\pgf@x * 0.03514598035 - \pt@sx}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pt@ey}{\pgf@y * 0.03514598035 - \pt@sy}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pt@len}{\pt@ex * \pt@ex + \pt@ey * \pt@ey}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pt@t}{(\pt@ax * \pt@ex + \pt@ay * \pt@ey)/\pt@len}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pt@t}{(\pt@t > .5 ? 1 - \pt@t : \pt@t)}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pt@h}{(\pt@ax * \pt@ey - \pt@ay * \pt@ex)/\pt@len}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pt@y}{\pt@h/(3 * \pt@t * (1 - \pt@t))}%
      }
      (\tikztostart) .. controls +(\pt@t * \pt@ex + \pt@y * \pt@ey, \pt@t * \pt@ey - \pt@y * \pt@ex) and +(-\pt@t * \pt@ex + \pt@y * \pt@ey, -\pt@t * \pt@ey - \pt@y * \pt@ex) .. (\tikztotarget)
    }
  }
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill (0,0) circle[radius=2pt];
\fill (2,1) circle[radius=2pt];
\fill (5,5) circle[radius=2pt];
  \draw
   (0,0) to[through point={(2,1)}] (5,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and the result:

[image: path through a point]

If we put that in your code, we get the following, where the green line is that added by my code:

[image: path avoiding node]

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27899/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  through point/.style={
    to path={%
      \pgfextra{%
        \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone(\tikztostart)\relax
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pt@sx}{\pgf@x * 0.03514598035}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pt@sy}{\pgf@y * 0.03514598035}%
        \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1\relax
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pt@ax}{\pgf@x * 0.03514598035 - \pt@sx}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pt@ay}{\pgf@y * 0.03514598035 - \pt@sy}%
        \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone(\tikztotarget)\relax
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pt@ex}{\pgf@x * 0.03514598035 - \pt@sx}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pt@ey}{\pgf@y * 0.03514598035 - \pt@sy}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pt@len}{\pt@ex * \pt@ex + \pt@ey * \pt@ey}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pt@t}{(\pt@ax * \pt@ex + \pt@ay *           \pt@ey)/\pt@len}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pt@t}{(\pt@t > .5 ? 1 - \pt@t : \pt@t)}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pt@h}{(\pt@ax * \pt@ey - \pt@ay *           \pt@ex)/\pt@len}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pt@y}{\pt@h/(3 * \pt@t * (1 - \pt@t))}%
      }
      (\tikztostart) .. controls +(\pt@t * \pt@ex + \pt@y * \pt@ey, \pt@t * \pt@ey - \pt@y * \pt@ex) and +(-\pt@t * \pt@ex + \pt@y * \pt@ey, -\pt@t * \pt@ey - \pt@y * \pt@ex) .. (\tikztotarget)
    }
  }
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(a) {\(A\)};
\node(b1) at ($(a)+(4,1)$){\(B_1\)};
\node(b2) at ($(b1)+(0,-1)$){\(B_2\)};
\node(c) at ($(b1)+(1,-0.9)$){\(C\)};
\node(d) at ($(c)+(2,0)$){\(D\)};
\node(e) at ($(d)+(1,0.5)$){\(E\)};
\draw[->] (a) to[out=20,in=180] (b1);
\draw[->] (a) to[out=0,in=180] (b2);
\draw[->] (b1) to[out=0,in=160] (d);
\draw[->,red] (b2) to[out=0,in=180] (e);
\draw[->,red,dashed] (b2) to[out=-40,in=240] (e);
\draw[->,green] (b2) to[through point={(d.south east)}] (e);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As I said at the start, I think that the general problem will not be (easily) soluble (I'd be happy to be proved wrong ...).  So to get around this, I require you, the user, to decide which paths have to move, and to decide which side to move it.  The code then works out a nice (I hope!) path.

**Explanation of the code:** We want a bezier curve from the start to the finish through a particular point.  In general, this would involve solving a cubic equation which, while possible, isn't pleasant.  So we simplify the bezier.  Let's take a bezier, *a (1 - t)^3 + 3 b t (1 - t)^2 + 3 c t^2 (1 - t) + d t^3*, and transform our coordinates so that *a* is at the origin and *d* is at *(1,0)*.  Then if we pick the *x* coordinates of *b* and *c* to be *1/3*, the *x*-projection is linear.  This means that it is easy to figure out the time at which the bezier goes through a particular vertical line.

So to make it go through a particular point, say *(p,q)* with *p ∈ (0,1)*, we simply take *t = p*.  Then we also assume that the *y*-coordinates of *b* and *c* are the same (say *h*), whence we get the formula *h = q/(3 p (1 - p))*.

The code above does this, only we have to work in a different coordinate system, so we have lots of orthogonal projections going on.

Comment: Awesome solution. I assume the magic number 0.03514598035 is just a conversion from TeX points to cm?

Comment: @Peter: Yes (found it from some conversion website).  I found that if the numbers were in pt then the computations got too large so scaling down to cm made the calculations work.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. I have to admit that I'm clueless of how the code works. As for compiling I don't have the package `standalone` installed so I changed the document class to article and tried to compile the second code block and got `! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   ?
l.47 ...b2) to[through point={(d.south east)}] (e)`. Is it my old TikZ version (using Ubuntu 11.04's TeX Live 2009)?

Comment: @N.N.: Sorry, I shouldn't have left the `standalone` there.  It's a class that Martin developed for creating documents the same size as their contents.  It uses `article` internally so that should work.  But I probably do use stuff from a more recent version of PGF.  Ubuntu is *really old*.  You can just install a more up-to-date version of PGF if you don't want to install the whole of TL2011 (but I do recommend a full upgrade if possible).  There are questions here about how to do either (install TL2011 alongside Ubuntu, or just install PGF).

Comment: @AndrewStacey Cheers! I grabbed PGF from CTAN and installed it locally and it compiles fine now. Is it possible to get it to pass multiple points? I tried to add another `to` as in `\draw[->,green] (b2) to[through point={(c.south east)}] to[through point={(d.south east)}] (e);` but I get the following error `! Package tikz Error: (, +, coordinate, or node expected.`.

Comment: I follow this up this with a new question instead: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28459/automatically-avoid-more-than-one-node-when-drawing-a-path